A self-crossing image
The answer is a single word. What word?


The answer is

 LOOPS

Method:

 Note that there are 19 loops in total. Count the number of loops before a black cut-off line and note them down starting from the left starting point. Then convert the numbers into letters using the A1Z26 cipher.


 Doing so in order we get 12,15,15,16,19 ——-> L,O,O,P,S.


Correct, well done!

It works because the sequence is increasing
